# thread in multi core processor

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I have written a program in C, and I just want only one function running in another processor core.

Does anyone know how to distribute threads on different cores? Can a single running thread running on one core, can sometimes utilize another core as well, depending on how busy the cores are?

Comment: did this pass through some sort of machine translation?

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are looking for set affinity functionality.

```
Processor affinity is a modification of the native central queue scheduling 
algorithm in a symmetric multiprocessing operating system. Each task 
(be it process or thread) in the queue has a tag indicating its 
preferred / kin processor. At allocation time, each task is allocated to
its kin processor in preference to others.
```

Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407786/how-to-set-cpu-affinity-of-a-particular-pthread) which discusses the usage of setting affinity to particular thread. 
Excerpts from this thread:

```
int sched_setaffinity(pid_t pid,size_t cpusetsize,cpu_set_t *mask);

Passing 0 as the pid, and it'll apply to the current thread only, or have other
thread report their kernel pid with the linux specific call pid_t gettid(void);
and pass that in as the pid.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking how do threads get distributed to run on different processors in a multi-processor CPU?  If so, my understanding is that this is something that is controlled by the operating system.  Take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396137/multi-core-usage-threads-thread-pools).

Comment: First think you.

but, i don't want parallet with .NET, but with C unter Linux, ther es no api or c Libary!!!